# Find the specified particular solution of ($x^2+2y')y''+2xy'=0$ while $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In this problem I am able to understand that it must be solved using reduction of order. But I am not able to proceed with the sum & also I am confused of where to substitute the given values of $y$ and  $y'$.

Comment: I got stuck up again. I proceeded as you told but I am getting it as (x^2 + 2p)^2=x^4+C. Now how to separate the variables??. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 3):

We have$$2y'y''+x^2y''+2xy'=0$$by integrating we obtain$$(y')^2+(x^2y')+C=0$$since $y'(0)=0$ we have $C=0$ which yields to $$y'=0\\\text{and/or}\\ y'+x^2=0$$therefore$$y=D\\\text{and/or}\\ y'=-{x^3\over 3}+D$$once more we have $y(0)=1$ therefore $$y=1\\\text{and/or }\\y=1-{x^3\over 3}$$

Answer (score 1):

Start with $p=y'$ to get
$$\left(2 p+x^2\right) p'+2 x p=0\qquad \text{with}\qquad p(0)=0$$
Let now $$u=2p+x^2\implies p=\frac  {u-x^2}2\implies p'=\frac{u'-2x}2$$ Replace to get
$$\frac{1}{2} u u'-x^3=0$$ which seems to be easy to integrate.

When done, go back to $p$ and fix the constant of integration to get the condition.

Comment: I think you made a mistake: $p'=\dfrac{u'-2x}{2}$.

Comment: @Batominovski. Thanks for pointing the typo.